# Hide payment methods based select option?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Hi i want to show show payments methods based on country option selected.
i have following code.

> FOR COUNTRY SELECTION

```
          $countries = json_decode(file_get_contents(resource_path('views/partials/country.json')));
   


<select name="country" id="countriess" class="form-control">
                         
                 <option value="nil"> -- select an option -- </option>
                        @foreach($countries as $key => $country)
                      
                            <option data-mobile_code="{{ $country->dial_code }}" value="{{ $country->country }}" data-code="{{ $key }}">{{ __($country->country) }}</option>
                         
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
```

> To LOAD GATEWAYS

```
@foreach($gatewayCurrency as $data) // $data->country has country name from database

@endforeach
```

> I have tried following using jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           
   $('#countriess').on('change',function(){
     if("{{$data->country}}"!=$(this).val()){
            
      $("#country_{{$data->country}}").hide();
      
        }
       else if("{{$data->country}}"== $(this).val()){
           
        $("#country_{{$data->country}}").show();
        
        }
else if("{{$data->country}}"!=$(this).val()){
            
      $("#country_{{$data->country}}").hide();
      
        }
    });

        
        </script>
```

but issue is shows some other countries gateways as well if they are 2nd last in database

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for questioning here.
Below is the answer:

1. First add the `payment_methods` class in the payment methods element
2. Then add the below javascript code

```
$('#countries').on('change', function(){
  let countryId = $(this).val()  // get selected country id
  $('.payment_methods').hide();  // hide the all payment methods
  $("#country_" + countryId).show(); // then show payment methods for selected country id
});
```

Thanks!